# Migrating to "unwindForSegue()" from "segueForUnwindingToViewController()"

Tags: ios

The Apple API docs indicate that `segueForUnwindingToViewController()` is deprecated and that I should use `unwindForSegue()` instead for use with a custom segue. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707698/custom-unwind-segue-for-ios-8-and-ios-9) but they still appear to use "segueForUnwindingToViewController()".

I'm not sure how to properly use the `unwindForSegue()` because `segueForUnwindingToViewController()` took the following arguments

- toViewController
- fromViewController
- identifier

and returned a "UIStoryBoardSegue". E.g.

```
  override func segueForUnwindingToViewController(toViewController: UIViewController, fromViewController: UIViewController, identifier: String?) -> UIStoryboardSegue? {
    return MyCustomSegue(identifier: identifier!, source: fromViewController, destination: toViewController, performHandler: { () -> Void in } )
  }
```

How do I pass my identifier and create my custom segue instance using the new `unwindForSegue()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this is not so hard as it could seems to be. I presume there are quite few ways to set up your custom segue.

**Prerequisites:**

1. You need to create custom segue class for perform transition between UIViewControllers. Don't forget to set parent class - **UIStoryboardSegue**. (CustomSegue, for example)
2. You need to override method in your container view controller **-unwindForSegue:towardsViewController:** where you can populate your segue from code

*Important*, you do not need to override this method in your custom view controllers that are not containers

**One way**, you can select you segue in storyboard and set it Class to your segue class(for example, *CustomSegue*)

[Example where to set custom segue class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEvJf.png)

**Another way**, you can create segue from this method and simply perform it. For example,

```
- (void)unwindForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue towardsViewController:(UIViewController *)subsequentVC {
        CustomSegue *segue = [[CustomSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:<#Segue Identifier#> source:unwindSegue.sourceViewController destination:unwindSegue.destinationViewController];
        [segue perform];
}
```

Both method work properly. Hope this helps you.

---

P. S. You can try this test projects(Xcode 7.3) - https://github.com/igorkislyuk/custom-animation-unwind-segue